# Replacing Special Characters in Strings

Tags: java, groovy, str-replace

I've seen a lot of Q&A here on SO related to this question.  And I have used a few examples but something just isn't working:

```
def input = 'now is thé timé'
println Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll(/[^A-z0-9 ]/, "").replaceAll(/ +/, "-")
```

The output of the above is

```
now-is-th-tim
```

If I do the following:

```
String input = 'now is th\u00E9 tim\u00E9'
println Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll(/[^A-z0-9 ]/, "").replaceAll(/ +/, "-")
```

I get

```
now-is-the-time
```

which is what I want.  I even tried the following:

```
def input = groovy.json.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript('now is thé timé')
println Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll(/[^A-z0-9 ]/, "").replaceAll(/ +/, "-")
```

but I get

```
now-is-th\u221A\u00A9-tim\u221A\u00A9
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: Based on the comments, I tried the following:

```
import java.text.Normalizer

def input = new File('file.txt').text
def results = Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll(/[^A-z0-9 ]/, "")
    .replaceAll(/ +/, "-")
println results
```

file.txt contains the text I had placed in the string.  And that is working as expected.  So there is something going on with the encoding of the string definition in groovy.

Comment: He wants normalizer to normalize `é`, but it only seems to be working if he does `\u00E9`

Comment: @nhgrif: Which is é, indicating that it's an encoding problem.

Comment: Curiously, your first example in the groovyconsole gives me `now-is-the-time`?

Comment: @tim_yates I tested it in the groovy console and groovy web console and got the same results as you. So that's good news.  But still doesn't really solve the issue.  Doesn't make sense that an editor like sublime is causing encoding issues that differ from groovy.

Comment: I guess it depends what encoding sublime text is using.  Does running `locale` in a terminal window shed any light? (assuming Linux/OS X)

Comment: locale returns utf-8 and sublime is using utf-8.  I don't think it is a sublime issue, since the same problem happens in vi.  And, based on the update to the question, reading the text from a file (created with sublime) works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your second snippet works, I strongly suspect that for the first snippet the encoding you're using in your editor isn't the same as the encoding your Groovy interpreter/compiler is using.

In other words, the problem isn't in the *second* line of your code - it's in the *first* line. You're not starting with the input text that you think you are.

Comment: Well, that's all fine and good.  I'm using sublime right now to test this out. What's the solution?  How do I sync up the encoding?

Comment: Writing the same code in VI has the same results, the é gets removed.

Comment: @Gregg: Well you need to find out what encoding you're using in Sublime, and find out how it's running Groovy (or whatever you're running it in), and see if you can pass in the encoding.